# Run a spring-boot project but pages of another project show up

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

The keyword is too verbose to help me find anything useful. Please pardon me if it's a stupid question.

I have two spring-boot projects, A and B, in the same directory. I run

```
mvn clean
mvn compile
mvn package
mvn spring-boot:run
```

in the directory of project A and want to run A. However, the pages of project B shows up (both of them use localhost:8080).

I tried the following but none worked:

1. Moved and renamed A to another directory and ran all the above commends again;
2. Clean brower cache or open in incog window;
3. Remove .m2 folder;
4. Reboot my laptop;
5. Run with IDE, `mvn spring-boot:run`, and `java -jar target/ProjectA.jar`;
6. Invalidate Cache/Restart in IntelliJ.

Also:

1. If I break Project A (make it fail to compile), `mvn compile` will fail;
2. If I break Project B, running A will still give me B;
3. If I change the contents of html files in B, it won't change the showing pages;
4. If I debug the project A, it will hit the main function in @SpringBootApplication;
5. Everything is running on Win10, no container or VM.

It seems I am running Project A, but it has neither MvcConfig nor html templates, where are those pages from? I did a thorough search for page contents, but the project directory of A didn't contain anything like that. So it must from somewhere else.

Github: https://github.com/PhoenixPan/finishthem-api-server
(doesn't have any visible html page)

Hope someone could explain why this is happening and how should I prevent it... Thanks.

Comment: Clean up (delete)the content of  .m2 folder.

Comment: Thanks @georgesvan I thought that should resolve the solution as well, but...it doesn't :(

Comment: Quite weird.. when A starts and you see pages from B, does it work as B was supposed to work? Have you tried cleaning your browser's cache?

Comment: Thanks for answering. @DiogoSilvério, No, I broke project B, it doesn't even compile now. Browser cache is cleaned and I also tried incog window. It seems the entire project B is cached somewhere else...I ran through `mvn spring-boot:run` and IDE start, both get the same thing (project B)

Comment: Maybe if you Reinstall jdk and Maven ? Or load your apps on GitHub so we can see

Comment: @georgesvan Sure! I have updated with Github link. Running the project shouldn't give any html page

Comment: Just curious, why do both projects have to run on the same port? Can you change them and try?

Comment: @NicholasK Yeah, I will try that when I get home today. Currently, I am more concerned about why this is happening and where did A pick up those html pages, cause there should be none...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old question. But if any of the newcomers came up with an issue like this. Please check your dependencies. for example when you load dependencies like "thymeleaf", in dependencies you can find something like this.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and when you guys access to localhost:8080/ it automatically reirected to  localhost:8080/login.

[image: http://localhost:8080/login]

[image: login for with out view]

at that point, you can complain that "I don't have any view file (jsp, HTML) but I am getting unexpected browser page. **You have to comment or remove mentioned dependency in your pom.xml file**.

[image: comment on it]
and then try again. good luck happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your project A from your IDE as a simple java application? You can run a Spring Boot application from your IDE as a simple Java application. However, you first need to import your project. Import steps vary depending on your IDE and build system. Most IDEs can import Maven projects directly. For example, Eclipse users can select Import…​ → Existing Maven Projects from the File menu.

Comment: Hi @afaq, yeah, I tried both `mvn spring-boot:run` and run ProjectA in IntelliJ, nothing has changed :(